# Removing One String CSV elements from another CSV String in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to remove elements from one CSV string with other CSV string :

**Example:**

```
String s1= "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,w,p,4,5,12,u,v"; /* Base String */

String s2="e,5,v";` /*(input string) This elements has to remove from above string S1 */
```

Expected Output String `s1: "a,b,c,d,f,g,h,w,p,4,12,u";`

I have Tried:  For loop and remove elements and append back String.

I can to this by no. of ways, but i want to know if there is any library/method/utility available ?

Answer (score 1):

try to use [String::replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) with some regex like this :

```
String regexReplace = "[" + s2.replace(",", "") + "]";//result [e5v]
s1 = s1.replaceAll(regexReplace, "") // replace all character in class [e5v] with empty
        .replaceAll(",{2,}", ",")// replace all two or more comma with one comma
        .replaceAll("(^,|,$)", "");// in some cases replace comma in start or in the end
```

General solution (to match words and not letters) you can use this instead :

```
String regexReplace = "(" + s2.replace(",", "|") + ")";// result (e|5|v)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try StringUtil from Spring

```
String s1= "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,w,p,4,5,12,u,v"; /* Base String */
String s2="e,5,v";
System.out.println(StringUtils.deleteAny(s1, s2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringUtils class from apache commons [Reference](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#remove-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)